# How to escape '<' character for use within php echo command

Tags: apache2, php, html

My webserver outputs the result of a fortune/cowsay combo.  My php script is similar to this:

```
<?php
$output = shell_exec('/var/www/bin/fortune -a -o -s | /var/www/bin/cowsay -f eyes');

echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
```

However this particular cow file poses a problem.  Instead of this result achieved with the console:

```
 __________________________________
/ You will overcome the attacks of \
\ jealous associates.              /
 ----------------------------------
    \
     \
                                   .::!!!!!!!:.
  .!!!!!:.                        .:!!!!!!!!!!!!
  ~~~~!!!!!!.                 .:!!!!!!!!!UWWW$$$ 
      :$$NWX!!:           .:!!!!!!XUWW$$$$$$$$$P 
      $$$$$##WX!:      .<!!!!UW$$$$"  $$$$$$$$# 
      $$$$$  $$$UX   :!!UW$$$$$$$$$   4$$$$$* 
      ^$$$B  $$$$\     $$$$$$$$$$$$   d$$R" 
        "*$bd$$$$      '*$$$$$$$$$$$o+#" 
             """"          """""""
```

the page served is:

```
 ________________________________________
< You have taken yourself too seriously. >
 ----------------------------------------
    \
     \
                                   .::!!!!!!!:.
  .!!!!!:.                        .:!!!!!!!!!!!!
  ~~~~!!!!!!.                 .:!!!!!!!!!UWWW$$$ 
      :$$NWX!!:           .:!!!!!!XUWW$$$$$$$$$P 
      $$$$$##WX!:      .
```

I have made an attempt of using `str_replace` to insert `chr(60)` but have not had any success this way.

How can I make my php script robust to all text characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the PHP function [htmlentities](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) to replace any HTML special characters using HTML escape characters.
To use it you would change you code to look something like this:

```php
<?php
$output = shell_exec('/var/www/bin/fortune -a -o -s | /var/www/bin/cowsay -f eyes');

$encoded = htmlentities($output);
echo "<pre>", $encoded, "</pre>";
```

As per this  **demo** - http://codepad.viper-7.com/VZOI5u

#### Explanation

Whenever PHP output contains characters like `<` the webrowser will (correctly) presume its HTML - e.g. the browser will assume the `<` is the beginning of a HTML code sequence like `<b>hello</b>`.
the htmlentities function will replace those special characters with escape sequences - which the browser knows to simply display to screen and not interpret as being "special" HTML characters. so for example `<b>hello</b>` becomes `&lt;b&gt;hello&lt;/b&gt;`